# Angular2 with Typescript simple example with local variables

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to build a little app with Angular2. I want to use local variables, like it is explained here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

```html
<input #myname (keyup)>
<p>{{myname.value}}</p>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. If i press a key on the focused input field, the text in the p-tag should be updated. But all i get is an Exception:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: rec[(rec.length - 1)] is undefined

If i do something like this it will work, even if the foo method exists or not:

```html
<input #myname (keyup)="foo()">
<p>{{myname.value}}</p>
```

I followed exactly the instructions on the page and i don't have any custom code.

Comment: I think it's bug, create [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4615)

Comment: when you use the (event) notation you  must provide the function  to be called ..

The examples in the angular.io site are not up to date ( they use 2.0.0-alpha.37 .. the current version is alpha39 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#get-user-input-from-a-local-template-variable) have been updated:

```
<input #box (keyup)="0">
```

> ... an Event Binding requires a template expression to evaluate when the
>   event fires. Many things qualify as expressions, none simpler than a
>   one-character literal like the number zero. That's all it takes to
>   keep Angular happy.